# YouTube acting weird in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

Frequently YouTube gets screwed up in my Chrome (both on Mac and Win7)... the thumbnails on the right are blank, cannot vote or comment (seems like javascript is turned off).

What helps is to clear the browsing history and cookies (for the last hour is enough).
But the problem comes back after a short time...

anyone else with this problem?

thank you

Comment: Try hitting Ctrl+F5 when it happens.

Comment: I'm currently on Mac... Ctrl+F5 does nothing.. but I have tried clicking the refresh button while holding down Ctrl before.. and it doesn't help at all :/

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before, but it was a connection issue rather than one related to Chrome. Try disconnecting from the network and reconnecting.

Comment: I believe this is a suggestion. Request you to post them as a comment if you are not sure if that is a solution. (Avoid down-vote - frankly speaking)

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl+shift+I and click network, refresh your page to see if some elements on page are delayed because ajax requests are delayed. I presume your problem was due to the delays in network.

if you want to know where the problem is in the network, you can open cmd and enter

tracert www.youtube.com

and see at what point packages are delayed on the world wide web

Answer (score 0):

When I payed a video, it would *play for a second or two and then pause again*. This happened to me quiet a few times. Temporary solution that worked for me was **pressing ctrl+refresh**. I own a **chromebook** so things might be a bit different. Well, hope it really helps.

Comment: press flag and ask a mod to convert this to a comment for you since you don't have enough rep yet.